# How to test method with `rand` in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

I have a page which either returns "No match." or one of the model objects names.
What is the best way to test it with Cucumber? Should I stub rand in `Given` step or should I provide something like `page has either a or b`? Or maybe I should provide `rand` parameters in scenarion outline parameter, use this parameter in `Given` step and use the second outline column to check the result?

**UPDATE:** `cookies` controller example in the best traditions of Cookie Monster:

**cookie_controller.rb**

```
  def random_cookie
    if rand(5) == 0 do
      cookie = Cookie.offset(rand(Cookie.count)).first
      response =  "You got 10 free #{cookie.type} cookies for your purchase!"
    else
      response = "Sorry, no cookies left :'("
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { response: response } }
  end
```

**find_cookie.feature**

```
Scenario: Looking for cookie
    When I click "find"
    Then I should see "You got 10 free" or "Sorry, no cookies left :'("
```

How would `Then I should see "You got 10 free" or "Sorry, no cookies left :'("` step look?
I've tried something like

```
  (page.should have_content "You got 10 free") || (page.should have_content "Sorry, no cookies left :'("
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the properties of tests is that they should be repeatable: they should produce the same results each time, every time. Tests should not rely in uncontrollable params (like external resources, or random sources).

My point is that you will need two tests, one that checks for “You got 10 free” and another one that checks “Sorry, no cookies left”.

In the documentation of `rand`, you can find this snippet: “`Kernel::srand` may be used to ensure repeatable sequences of random numbers between different runs of the program.”, so if your write your scenarios with a setup step that sets the seed to some number that you know results (always) in one result or the other you will have your tests.

```
Scenario: Looking for cookie and finding it
  When I seed with X
  And click "find"
  Then I should see "You got 10 free"
Scenario: Looking for cookie and not finding it
  When I seed with Y
  And click "find"
  Then I should see "Sorry, no cookies left :'("


When /^I seed with (\d+)$/ do |seed|
  srand(seed.to_i)
end
```

You will need to find which seeds give you one result or the other, but once you find them, they will work forever.

Comment: Actually, once you set `srand` to a fixed number in the test, the errors should tell you the sequence of the results, so you basically can ask the tests to give you that information.

Answer (score 1):

Don't test random behaviour as this goes against proper software design practices. Your tests should be deterministic.

A way to wrest control of this is to define a module or class that can be substituted or mocked as required:

```
def random_cookie
  if CookieDealer.free_cookie?
    # ...
  end
end
```

The method would look like:

```
require 'securerandom'

module CookieDealer
  def self.free_cookie?
    SecureRandom.random_number(5) == 0
  end
end
```

You can then mock the `free_cookie?` method to simulate various conditions.

You will, of course, want to test the `free_cookies` method itself in a unit test of some sort. In this case you might want to run a very large number of tests to be sure it hands out approximately the correct number of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set the random seed, perhaps storing the original to restore it after testing is done.

See documentation here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-srand for 1.9.3 or documentation for Ruby 2.0.0 here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-srand